# Programming Linux

Tags: application-development

I want to make an application in c#, or in c++ or in what ever programming language even in script language as bash.

The application will ask for an answer, e.g. 1+1? and the password will be 2
If it is right then will log you in.
I dont want to answer how i will write the application, just how to implement that action in linux.

How can i accomplish that in ubuntu. (10.04 or 12.04)

Thank you in advance,
Best regards thio

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: If the homework requires from the app to get a 256-bit key and authenticate login through the network, yes could be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The code does not provide ways to authenticate through some network infrastructure using 256-bit key. It merely provides a plan to work on. The OP will have to build on the plan to complete his homework...*

Bellow is a simple Python code performing a small puzzle game representing most of the requested logic. See the comments in code for online resources about Python and some hints about each line of code.

**Update**

Added code to start X server as requested by the OP. The code uses the subprocess module.
I have not tested the start_x function but it should be close to the requested functionality.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""A mini puzzle game using Python 2.7.5 programming language
and the random module from the standard library.
See:
Website http://www.python.org
Python 2.7.5 documentation http://docs.python.org/2/
Online Python books
http://www.diveintopython.net/
http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonBooks
"""
import random
#import the subprocess module
import subprocess


def do_ask_random_sum_result():
    """Asks for the result of the addition of two random integers"""

    # get the two random integers from
    # a set of integers {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    first_random = random.randint(0,5)
    second_random = random.randint(0,5)

    # perform addition and store the
    # result to random_sum
    random_sum = first_random + second_random
    # print the two random numbers to output
    # asking the user for the result of their
    # addition
    result = input("What is the sum of {0} + {1}? ".format(
        first_random, second_random))
    # check if the user input matches
    # the result
    if random_sum == result:
        # instead of printing something
        # perform the log in to whatever you
        # want the user to log in
        print("That is correct, the result is: {0}".format(random_sum))
        print("Performing log in procedures...")
    # Cannot perform the log in since
    # the user provided a wrong answer...
    else:
        print ("Wrong answer!")

def do_login():
    """Performs the login"""

    # perform various login actions
    # 
    # and finally try to start X server
    try:
        # call the start_x function
        start_x()
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Could not start X server")
        print ("Error details:\n{err}".format(err=e.message))

def start_x():
    """Starts the x server using the subprocess module
        NOT TESTED but it must be something close to this
    """

    #declare proc as new process to launch
    proc = subprocess.Popen("startx", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    #assign the output of proc to output variable this is optional
    #for just to check what x has to say
    output = subprocess.stdout.read()
    #print the results
    print (output)

def main():
    """Application's main entry"""

    do_ask_random_sum_result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This snippet is very nice and thank y very much. Can someone provide me some solution for do_login() function. How can login a user and start startx server through python?

Comment: @Thio i have added a start_x function to start the X server but it is not tested. As for the login i don't know what exactly are the requirements when you say *login* but this is something you  should analyze as a part of your homework.